# Quadratic Equation program

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to learn more about C++ programming and I am having difficulty with a program. This program is simple but I am getting an error and I think it may have to do with pointers. I have tried modifying the code numerous times and I have not found the issue with what I have written. Any help or instruction on how to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
// The 'main' function for a program to test your function
// 'quadRoots'.
//===============================================================
#include <iostream>

int  quadRoots(double a,double b, double c,double* r1,double* r2);
void printRoots(int nr,double* r1,double* r2);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double root1[2], root2[2];
int nRoots;

// example with real roots
nRoots = quadRoots(1.0, 3.3, 2.1, root1, root2);
printRoots(nRoots,root1,root2);

// example with complex roots
nRoots = quadRoots(1.0, 3.3, 5.1, root1, root2);
printRoots(nRoots,root1,root2);

// example with real roots, one zero
nRoots = quadRoots(1.0, 3.3, 0.0, root1, root2);
printRoots(nRoots,root1,root2);

// example of a linear function that should produce 1 root
nRoots = quadRoots(0.7-1.0+0.3, 3.3, 2.1, root1, root2);
printRoots(nRoots,root1,root2);

// example that has no solutions
nRoots = quadRoots(0.7-1.0+0.3, 0.0, 5.5, root1, root2);
printRoots(nRoots,root1,root2);

cout << "Press Enter key to quit" << endl;
char qq = cin.get();

return(0);
}

void printRoots(int nr,double* r1,double* r2)
{
if(nr == 0){
    cout << "No Roots" << endl << endl;
}
else if(nr == 1){
    cout << "Root 1: " << r1[0] << endl << endl;
}
else if(fabs(r1[1]) < 0.0000001){   // print real roots
    cout << "Root 1: " << r1[0] << endl;
    cout << "Root 2: " << r2[0] << endl << endl;
}
else{  // print complex roots
    if(fabs(r1[1]+r2[1]) > 0.00001){
        cout << "Something is wrong: complex roots not in conjugate pairs."         << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Root 1: " << r1[0] << " + " << fabs(r1[1]) << " i" << endl;
        cout << "Root 2: " << r2[0] << " - " << fabs(r2[1]) << " i" << endl << endl;
    }
}
}
int quadRoots(double a,double b,double c,double* r1,double* r2)
{
if ( a > 0 ){
    if ( sqrt((b*b) - 4*a*c) > 0 ){
        r1[0] = (-b + (sqrt((b*b) - 4*a*c))) / (2 *a);
        r2[0] = (-b - (sqrt((b*b) - 4*a*c))) / (2 *a);
        return (2);
    }
    else if (sqrt((b*b) - 4*a*c) == 0 ) {
        r1[0] =  (-b )/(2 *a);
        return (1);
    }
    else if (sqrt((b*b) - 4*a*c) < 0 ) {
        r1[1] = (-b + (-(sqrt(-(b*b) - 4*a*c)))) / (2 *a);
        r2[1] = (-b - (-(sqrt(-(b*b) - 4*a*c)))) / (2 *a);
        return (2);
    }
}
else if (b == 0 ){
    r1[0] = r2[0] = 0;
    return (1);
}
else {
    return (0);
}
}
```

Comment: what actually does  happen when you compile/run this?

Comment: "I am getting an error" - Error messages contain important information about what the problem is. Always explain exactly what the error is you get.

Comment: When I run the program it states that the roots are not conjugate pairs and will display the roots properly in the print roots function. My question is, have I made an error in saving the roots improperly or is this a math mistake? I am very eager to learn more about c++ but this has confounded me for three days now! Thanks for the help and I hope I have clarified my issue.

Comment: why are you representing your roots as arrays like that?

Comment: can you post the output of your program?

Comment: Yes the roots are displaying as arrays, r1[0] is for the real root, where r1[1] is for imaginary roots.

Comment: Your calculations look a bit off. The result of the `double` overload of `sqrt` is the positive root, and its argument can't be negative.

Comment: Sure this is the output in the control window                           Something is wrong: Complex roots are not in conjugate pairs.

Comment: molbdnilo, I see what your saying, how should i modify that section of code, should i use fabs function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quadratic Equation c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954398/quadratic-equation-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (b*b - 4*a*c) < 0
are you forgot the real part of root?

Why you test the coefficent 'a'?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation
I hope this help you.

PS:
try this

```
int quadRoots(double a,double b,double c,double* r1,double* r2)
{
if ( a != 0 ){
    // 2nd order equation
    if ( b*b - 4*a*c > 0 ){
        r1[0] = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2 *a);
        r2[0] = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2 *a);
        r1[1] = 0;
        r2[1] = 0;
        return (2);
    }
    else if ( b*b - 4*a*c == 0 ) {
        r1[0] =  (-b )/(2 *a);
        r2[0] =  0;
        r1[1] =  0;
        r2[1] =  0;
        return (1);
    }
    else {
        // ( b*b - 4*a*c IS < 0 )
        // complex roots
        r1[0] = -b / (2 *a);
        r2[0] = -b / (2 *a);

        r1[1] = sqrt( 4*a*c - b*b) / (2 *a);
        r2[1] = -r1[1];
        return (2);
    }
}
else if (b != 0 ){
    // firts order equation
    r[0] = -c/b;
    return (1);
}
else {
    // a == 0 && b == 0
    // c = 0 ???
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @GMERiello, I have compiled and run your code and this is a huge help as I have made a silly mistake forgetting the real part of the complex root. But when I do run this program, for the case of two real roots I still get that the conjugate pairs do not match up.

Comment: I have updated the code, what you mean "for the case of two real roots I still get that the conjugate pairs do not match up", if real the conjugate part IS 0

Answer (score 3):

Lines of this form are suspect;

```
 if ( sqrt((b*b) - 4*a*c) > 0 )
```

as you will be calling sqrt on a negative.

You should check the real case, for example, by doing this:

```
if (b*b - 4*a*c > 0)
```

I've also dropped the unnecessary brackets. `*` has higher precedence than `-`. Only call the `sqrt` function on a non-negative parameter.

Comment: Thank you Bathseba I have modified my code and run it. I still see an error when running it in debug mode (Visual Studio 2012) that says not all control paths are returning a value, although I think I do have a return statement in each of these control structures, is that why I am displaying NAN for complex roots?

Comment: The compiler is not smart enough (or the standard doesn't guarantee enough) to determine that at least one branch of your `if/else if/else if/` branch on the value of `b*b - 4*a*c` must be true.  Use `else` for the last case.

Comment: You get NAN for the complex case as you are not calculating the conjugate pairs correctly: you need to run through the mathematics again.

Answer (score 0):

There is one aspect of numerical analysis that you are not aware of.  Suppose you have the quadratic equation

```
x^2 - 100 x + 1 = 0.
```

The two solutions are `(100 ± √9996)/2`.  Consider the root with th enegative sign:  `(100 - √9996)/2`.  Here. `100` and `√9996` are very close to each other; the subtraction will lose you about `4` significant digits. Instead you can use the fact that:

```
(-b ± √(b^2-4ac))/(2a) = 2c/(-b ∓ √(b^2-4ac)).
```

Then, you choose the signs so you don't subtract nearly equal numbers.  If `b` is positive, `-b` is negative, so choose the minus signs.  If `b` is negative, choose the plus signs.