# Quadratic Equation c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program for users to input for a, b, c to find the quadratic equation.

Please help so I can learn my errors.

```
#include < iostream>
#include < cmath>
#include < string>


using namespace std;

//////Quadratic Formula///////

int a;

int b;

int c;

float top1;

float left1;

float left2

float under3;

float under4; 



int main()

{

 ////////////////////User Input a, b, c///////////////////////

cout << "This program will allow you to input numbers for variables a, b, and c to    find the quadratic equation" << endl;

cout << "Enter a number for a: ";
cin >> a;

if (a == 0) //If user enters 0 it will quit the program and give them error message.
{
cout << "0 is not a sufficient coefficient for this program.";
cout <<"Restart now and try again." << endl;
exit(0);
}

cout << "Enter a number for b: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Enter a number for c: ";
cin >> c;

//////////////Calculations////////////

//////////////////b add
float top1 = (b*b)- 4*a*c);

float left1 = (-b) + sqrt(top1);

float under3 =  (left1))/(2*a);

/////////////b subtract

float top1 = (pow(b,2) - 4*a*c);

float left2 = (-b) - sqrt(top1);

float under4 =  (left2))/(2*a);




cout <<"The Answer for the Quadratic equation is:";
cout << under3(a, b, c,) <<endl;   // function call


cout <<"The first Root Value = " << under3 << endl; 
cout <<"The second Root Value = " << under4 << endl;


system("pause") ;

return 0;
}



 //px = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
 //nx = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
```

Comment: This isn't a question. Is there a problem with the current code? Is there an error message? Do you want a review of the code?

Comment: You create global variables and then create new local variables of the same name. Remove the global variables and use only local ones. Don't put spaces after the `<` in your include statements.

Comment: I would suggest you use fewer variables and combine the calculation into one block, the way you have it commented out at the bottom.  If your code is working, you should request a review from Code Review to learn what you are doing wrong.

Comment: This code is, unfortunately, not compilable; you're missing a semicolon, and your parenthesis are mismatched in multiple locations.

Comment: my error is expected `,' or `;' before ')' token   for   float top1 = (b*b)- 4*a*c);    thank you , you guys helped a lot.

Comment: First off, **format your code.** Currently, it's an unreadable mess.

Comment: If your code works and you want to get advice on how to make it better, you should post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One slightly unrelated suggestion I have for your a==0 error check is to use a do while statement instead of having your program close. It would look like this:

```
do
{
cout << "Enter a number for a: ";
cin >> a;
    if (a==0)
    {
    cout << "Can't use 0 for a.";
    }
} while (a==0);
```

This makes it so the user doesn't have to restart the program if they input an invalid number. Just a suggestion.

Comment: The trouble is that repeats the exit condition twice.

Comment: @NeilKirk would it? I didn't double check the code on my compiler but I'm pretty sure it'd work correctly. OP would have to delete his current error check of course.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to have the same logic twice. What if the code and condition is non-trivial and someone updates one but forgets to update the other.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm having a hard time following. What logic are you talking about having twice? Do you mean my if and do while conditions? I think for this program, it doesn't matter if you have those two because a can never equal 0 or else the quad equation won't work.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm curious how you would go about this.

Comment: `for (;;) { cin >> a; if (a == 0) { cout << "bad"; } else { break; } }`

Comment: @NeilKirk ah yes, that would definitely work. How is that necessarily better though? Because having two identical conditions is bad?

Comment: What if the condition is `a == b > 5 + i << (t * m - 2)` and somebody changes it and forgets to update the other one? It is also slightly inefficient to repeat the check twice, but not a big deal in this case.